# creating simple CRUD-extension for Typo3

Tags: crud, typo3

I'm making some first steps in Typo3 and am currently trying to make a simple CRUD extension. I want to be able to edit a db-table - create records, read them, edit them and finaly delete them. Just something like phpMyAdmin does, but just in the Typo3 BE.

But I can't find anything about CRUD and Typo3. I've created my extension with kickstart and already created the table, I've found a way to read its content and print it in the BE, but how do I make the other things? Is there a tutorial, or does anyone know a simple extension that does something similar I can look into to learn how it's done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by adding the table in the kickstarter and installing the extension, you can modify the records of this table through the List module. So I don't know, what else you want to do with this records (as the whole CRUD thing (for BE editors) is handled by the list module).

If you want to display the records in Frontend, you have to create a Plugin, which makes some output (probably based on the records in your table..).

Comment: That FE-plugin would be the next step. I'll have a look at the List module, thanks!

Comment: I accepted this answer, as it fitted better to my needs. Extbase might be the future, but the list module is included in Typo3 and can be used out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Typo3 version 4.3 or later, I strongly advise you to have a look at the extbase/fluid MVC Framework and Extbase Kickstarter extension. By default, Extbase Kickstarter allows you to create models of any complexity and generate simple CRUDs for the models.
BTW it can be a nice introduction to Flow3 and Typo3 v5, which should be released in stable version soon.
You can download blog_example from TER as a nice example to delve into.

I also found this tutorial but hadn't read it through : http://mocsystems.com/tutorials/writing-backend-modules-with-extbase/

Comment: Yeah, that looks nice. I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Of course, this is the future any you might directly want to learn Extbase instead of Pi-based Frontend Plugins! FLOW3 will be stable within the next few months. TYPO3v5 hopefully by the end of next year.